# Pre-filling a django form only if object is not 'None'

Tags: django, python-3.x, forms

I have a django form that pre-fills with certain data:

```
def edit_song(request, song_id):
"""Edit a song."""
song = Song.objects.get(id=song_id)

if request.method != 'POST':
    # Initial request; pre-fill form with current song info.
    producers = []
    for producer in song.producer.all():
        producers.append(producer.name)


    data = {'artist':song.artist.name, 'producer':", ".join(producers),
            'label':song.label.name}
    form = AddSongForm(instance=song, initial=data)
```

This works fine unless the 'label' object is 'None' (which is possible because it's optional), in which case I get the following error message:

AttributeError at /great_songs/edit_song/727/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

How do I make the django form pre-fill label ONLY if it is NOT a 'NoneType' object?

Answer (score 0):

You can "patch" the dictionary if `label` is not `None`:

```
data = {'artist':song.artist.name, 'producer':", ".join(producers)}
if song.label is not None:
    data['label'] = song.label.name
```

Comment: what exactly is 'patching' though?

Comment: @Leaozinho: well it is not official lexicon, it is more that we make a small change to the dictionary: we associate the `'label'` key with `song.label.name`, that is all.